# htaccess REQUEST_URI works for urls but not IP addresses in Wordpress default htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I'm getting pretty confused my htaccess file.

If I use the following directives:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} distribute$
RewriteRule (.*) BalanceManager.php [L]
```

Then I expect `https://somehwhere.com/distribute` to redirect to `https://somehwhere.com/BalanceManager.php` with `POST` data in place... this is exactly what happens, which is great.

I also expect `https://184.22.345.77/distribute` to redirect to `https://184.22.345.77/BalanceManager.php` with `POST` data in place. It does NOT do this, it throws a 404 not found.

I need this to work on IP addresses and under SSL protocol, but have failed to get anything to work yet.

Is there a right way to do this? Are there alternative ways to acheive this?

I can address the file directly, using `https://somehwhere.com/BalanceManager.php` and that works, but when I look up `https://184.22.345.77/BalanceManager.php` in my browser, it throws a 404.

The host is within the Amazon Web Services architecture, and importantly... **I am using a load balanced Wordpress site.**

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need this to work on IP addresses and under SSL protocol, but have failed to get anything to work yet.

Your IP is probably pointing to your default vhost and not the vhost that serves `somehwhere.com`. That's why you can't get to `https://184.22.345.77/BalanceManager.php`. Additionally, your SSL certificate won't work for an IP address if you've made the CA-Request for `somehwhere.com`. Browsers will load it and give you a certificate error because the IP isn't `somehwhere.com`.

If you don't care about the certificate error, you could add this line to your `somehwhere.com` vhost config (inbetween the `<VirtualHost> </VirtualHost>` block):

```
ServerAlias 184.22.345.77
```

Comment: That's a good idea but unfortunately going to https://184.22.345.77/anything-u-like/ does work (unsure now if it shows a certificate error, don't think it does). This is a Wordpress site.. I need to override the default routing for WP I think, will try again tomorrow.

Comment: Actually I see what you mean now (still haven't had a chance to work on it). I may need to use the server's internal network IPs instead...